# Hash Structure in Java issues

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, hashtable

Here is the HW problem:

At this point, you decide to implement a Hash structure for the contributor data to prepare for searches. You will read the contributor information from a file provided; it is a comma delimited (CSV) file. As each record is read, create a Hash table for the ID field. The limitation for the Hash table is that it has a size of 5, so you need to be able to handle collisions. Collisions should be resolved through the use of a linked list for the ID values (implement this using a stack). Your design should include the following:

A Hash table pointing to a structure for a linked list that contains only the following information:

Each Hash Bucket Collision Item will have the following Information:

ID: Integer; //identifier key for future needs
Hash Bucket Functions/Methods:

Input constructor: //to accept a string for the name and additional information for each contributor (you will only need the ID portion of the input data)
Hash Function constructor: (Hint: You only have 5 Hash buckets, so the function can be a very simple calculation.)
Pop constructor
Push constructor
Print constructor: //to show the contents of a Hash bucket
Deliverables:

A fully documented program to load the Hash table with collisions being handled as a linked list, implemented as a Stack
A test plan to show how the program runs and can be executed
A screenshot showing that the program loaded the data, and after all data is loaded, shows the contents of the first Hash bucket (ideally this is Bucket 0)

I believe I've gotten really close, but I'm used to Python so the Java syntax is something I'm trying to learn. Either way, check the code below to see what I've done.

I believe the problem has to do with the way I am declaring the hash table size. In python, I can just index the array and add a given object to that position in the array. Seems I can't do that in java though. I considered trying a for loop, but it didn't work

I feel like I'm pretty close. Most of the code was given from the professor, but I developed the Stack() class and methods on my own. When I run them they do work, and I got a 100% on that portion.

Through the debugging I've done, I can see that I am initializing an array of size 'size' (in this case 5). However, I can't figure out how to assign a key value pair to a given Stack() index.

Again, I'm used to Python and don't know much java, so I really think it's me not understanding Java syntax.

In python I would just do something along the lines of array[index].append[node]. Then, I could pop the array[index] and display the node one at a time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ContributorManager {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner inputFile = null;
        String name = null;
        String city = null;
        String country = null;
        String phone = null;
        double contribution = 0;
        int id = 0;
        Contributor c = null;
        Node node = null;
        HashTable h = new HashTable(5); 

        //open contributors file
        try {
            inputFile = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Dan/Desktop/contributors.csv"));
            System.out.println("AsdasdfaDSF");
            inputFile.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("(\\n)|(\\r)|,"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error opening file.");
        }

        //create contributors object for each row, and add to the stack
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            name = inputFile.next();
            city = inputFile.next();
            country = inputFile.next();
            phone = inputFile.next();
            contribution = inputFile.nextDouble();
            id = inputFile.nextInt();
            inputFile.nextLine(); //advance to the next line

            c = new Contributor(name, city, country, phone, contribution, id); 
            node = new Node(c);
            //System.out.println(c.hashFunction());
            h.insert(node); //insert node into the hash table
        }

        h.print(); //print the entire hash table
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Contributor {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private double contribution;
    private int id;

    public Contributor(String name, String city, String country, String phone, double contribution, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.contribution = contribution;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int hashFunction() {
        //calculate the hash key value using the id member variable in this object
        //the key must always return a value between 0 and 4
        int key = this.id % 5;
                return key;
        //return the hash key value
    }

    public void printContributor() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("City: " + city);
        System.out.println("Country: " + country);
        System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);
        System.out.println("Contribution: " + contribution);
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class HashTable {
    Stack[] table;
private int size;
    private int top;
        //declaring array

    public HashTable(int size) {
        //initialize the table array with empty Stack objects
        table = new Stack[size];
        System.out.println(table.length);



    }

    public void insert(Node n) {
        //determine the hash key of Node n
                System.out.println(n);
                int key = n.c.hashFunction();
                System.out.println(key);
        //using the key to determine the table location, 
        //push Node n onto the stack
                System.out.println(table.length);

                table[key].push(n);



    }

    public void print() {
        //display the contents of the entire table in order
        for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("===== Position " + i + " ======\n");
            table[i].print();
            System.out.println("========= End ==========");
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Node {
    Contributor c;
    Node next;

    public Node(Contributor data){
        //initialize member variables
        c=data;
        next=null;
    }

   public void displayNode() {
    //display the contents of this node
        c.printContributor();
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Stack {
    Node first; 

    public Stack(){
        //initialize the empty stack
        first = null;
    }

    public void push(Node newNode){
        //if the stack is empty, make first point to new Node.
        if(first==null)
            first=newNode;  
        //if the stack is not empty, loop until we get to the end of the list,
        //then make the last Node point to new Node
        else
        {
            first=newNode;
            newNode = newNode.next;
         }
    }

    public Node pop() { 
        //if the stack is empty, return null
        if(first==null)
            return null;
        //Handle the case where there is only one Node in the stack  
        else if(first.next==null)
        {
            Node t=first;
            return t;   
        }
        //Handle the case where there are at Least two (or more) elements in the stack
        else
        {
            Node t=first;
            return t;   
        }  
    }

    public void print() {
        //display the entire stack
        Node tempDisplay = first; // start at the beginning of linkedList
        while (tempDisplay != null){ // Executes until we don't find end of list.
            tempDisplay.displayNode();
            tempDisplay = tempDisplay.next;
        }  
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

contributor.csv

```
Tim,Murphy,USA,8285557865,200,25
Gordon,Miner,USA,8285551008,150,32
Jean,Bell,USA,8285557503,225,33
Mike,Prather,USA,8285558497,155,34
George ,Pipps,USA,8285557777,100,35
```

Comment: Your pop method seems off. Both the if and else statements do the same thing. You need to iterate to the end of the stack, then return and remove the last element

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can't figure out how to assign a key value pair to a given Stack() index.

A stack is not an array. Index assignment is not a supported operation, only push and pop from one end of the structure.

---

It looks like you're having problems with the push and pop operations? Your code comments indicate what needs to be done. *if stack is not empty, then **loop** to the end*

You have no loop, and you seem to be inserting into the stack backwards.

Instead you'd probably want something like the following, very similar to the print method

```
Node n = first;
while (n.next != null) n = n.next;
n.next = newNode;
```

Similarly for popping, you'd stop the loop when `n.next != null && n.next.next == null` so that you can set `n.next = null` and pop it off the list

```
//TODO: loop logic 
Node toPop = n.next;
n.next = null;
return toPop;
```